# ScrollPane only shows content after minimizing

Tags: swing, jpanel, scrollpane

After loading a pane with checkBoxes and then loading that back into the ScrollPane. Then I'm only able to see the new content after first minimizing then restoring the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use updateUI() method as

```
aScrollPane.updateUI();
```

that shoud refresh you graphics :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to do a repaint() on your ScrollPane when you switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `topLevelContainer.validate();` works just fine in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271).

[image]